# PHP define the key of an array from a value of an object

Tags: php

With PHP, I have list of Object. Each object have `id` field :

```
$myArray = [
    0 => Object{
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'My title 1'
    },
    1 => Object{
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'My title 2'
    },
    2 => Object{
        'id' => 6,
        'title' => 'My title 6'
    }
]
```

I want to set array key from `id` object **without additional foreach**.
I want this result :

```
$myArray = [
    1 => Object{
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'My title 1'
    },
    2 => Object{
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'My title 2'
    },
    6 => Object{
        'id' => 6,
        'title' => 'My title 6'
    }
]
```

I think it's possible with `array_map` but I don't know how to do it. I tried this but it returns sub array :

```
$newArray = array_map(function($entry) {
    return [$entry->id => $entry];
}, $myArray);

// return :

[
    0 => [
        1 => Object{
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'My title 1'
        },
    ],
    1 => [
        2 => Object{
            'id' => 2,
            'title' => 'My title 2'
        },
    ],
    2 => [
        6 => Object{
            'id' => 6,
            'title' => 'My title 6'
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: array_map will return a new array. You may try with array_walk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myArray = array_column($myArray, null, 'id');
```

Comment: This is better than the solution I was going to suggest, which combines `array_column` with `array_combine`.

Comment: This solution is cool

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
array_combine(array_column($myArray, 'id'), $myArray);
```

This way you will make the ID as the key and keep all the array related to id as the value for this index.